# Ctrl + v & Ctrl + c in terminal

Tags: command-line, clipboard

How can I make copy/paste in the Ubuntu 16.04 Shell? For example, pasting a string from my browser to the cli and execute it as a command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> not working by default)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For pasting text into the terminal, you can either use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or use your mouse's middle click if there is one.

For copying text in the terminal, you can either use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or use your mouse to select the text of interest and then use its middle click to paste it.

Comment: Important note: You can edit these shortcuts in `Edit > Key combinations` (translated from my spanish version of the Terminal), and set the legendary `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V`!

Comment: Yes. We can edit these in Terminal profile.

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a way to also enable `Ctrl + Backspace` to delete an entire word? Right now it works with `Ctrl + W`

Answer (score 7):

### Copy / Paste in Terminal

Copy:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
Paste: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

You may also find usage for:

Copy:  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
Paste: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>